# Split a string into smaller string by length

Tags: php

I am really new to PHP and I am trying split a string into a smaller string by a length, and then it returns an array of these small strings.

here is what I got so far:

```
    <?php

        $str = $_POST['input']; //It will get the string from the input
        $string = str_split($str, 4);

    for ($i=0; $i <strlen($str); $i++) { 
        $string[$i] = str_split($str,4);
    }

    ?>

<td>Output:</td>
<td align="center"><textarea rows="5" cols="50" readonly="readonly"><?php echo $string[$i]."\n"; ?></textarea></td>
```

Can anybody show me how can I return an array of the strings by length of 4? 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right. Just return after `str_split`

```
    $str = $_POST['input']; //It will get the string from the input
    $string = str_split($str, 4);  // this is a array of strings with lenght 4
    return $string;
```

The $string variable has the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hell
    [1] => oFri
    [2] => day
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I have to loop over the string and then print out, I put the `return $string` after `str_split` I didn't get anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: var_dump / print_r the $string and post here

Comment: Please see my updated code, for some reason when I add the return the textarea disappeared.

Comment: Remove the return and the loop after return, then see the output

Comment: I think I got it work. Thank you so much for your help!